# error: not found: value RANDOM

Tags: scala, apache-spark, fuzzy-c-means

I am trying to run Fuzzy C Means algorithm in Spark using Scala

I'm following below link for this:

https://github.com/acflorea/fuzzyCMeans

Click below to see screenshot of the error which I am receiving

Error Screenshot:
[image: img]

I am have used sbt then spark-shell

Furthermore, to resolve this,

I have tried to import below

```
import scala.util.Random
import java.util.Random
import util.Random
```

But Still I am getting the same error as before(screenshot)

Any help in this regard would be appreciated. Thanks!

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I have imported below mentioned package,

```
org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans
```

but I am still facing this issue. Kindly check the detailed screenshot:

[Screenshot of my work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgdPr.png)

Kindly Assist! Thank you!

PS: I am using Spark 1.6.0 and Scala 2.10.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two constants (RANDOM and K_MEANS_PARALLEL) are defined in `org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans`

Be careful, I have not updated the package since Spark1.6 hence Scala 2.10 :)

Enjoy!

Comment: In order to import everything from an object in Scala you should use:

`import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans._`

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

In Scala,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rand
```

rand is a function available in spark sql.
Importing this allows to access the rand function.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be great if you could support your answer with some explanation. In your case, the reason to use the `rand` from spark SQL.